# If we push from local to remote a commit that is merge of a branch commit X and feature commit Y but in the remote commit Y not present, will it work?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-push

I have this situation that I trying to understand.

```
at T1 Local                         |       at T1 Remote:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 E--F featureOne                    |        E--F featureOne
/                                   |       /
A--B--C--D branchOne                |       A--B--C--D branchOne
------------------------------------------------------------------------


at T2 Local                         |       at T2 Remote:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
merged branchOne into featureOne:   |
   E------F   featureOne            |    E--F featureOne    
  /        \                        |   /       
 /          G                       |   A--B--C--D branchOne                    
/          /                        |               
A--B--C----D branchOne              |                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------


at T3 Local                         |       at T3 Remote:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
merged featureOne into branchOne    |
after git pull branchOne            |
from Remote:                        |
   E------F                         |    E--F featureOne    
  /        \                        |   /       
 /          G-. featureOne          |   A--B--C--D branchOne                    
/          /   \                    |               
A--B--C----D-----H branchOne        |                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

H in local is a merge of commits between G of featureOne and D of branchOne. Because in remote we don't have G, what will happen say at T4, if I push branchOne from local to remote(origin/branchOne)? Will it merge?
Unfortunately, I cannot try this because I had pushed G first from local featureOne to remote featureOne and then pushed H from local branchOne to remote branchOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `git push` does is send your *commits*—some or all (or sometimes none) of the ones that you have, that some other Git doesn't have—to the other Git in question, then ask that other Git to set some of *their names* to some commit hash ID.

So if you have:

> ```
>  E--F--G____
> /       \   \
> A--B--C--D--H
> ```

in your repository—regardless of where any of your branch *names* point—and you tell your Git to send commit `H` to some other Git, your Git will call up the other Git and offer it commit `H`.

(Note: I assume here that commit `G` is a merge of `F` and `D`.  Your question description makes it clear that this is the case.  I'd draw the graph a bit differently myself; see below.)

(The same reasoning would apply if you ask your Git explicitly to send them commit `G`, but in this particular case, your Git has to offer `G` after offering `H` and having them accept, so we'll just worry about `H` here.  Plus, you asked about `git push branchOne`, with your name `branchOne` pointing to commit `H`.)

If they have commit `H`, this part of the `git push` is done.  In this case they don't have commit `H`, so your Git will offer commits `G` and `D` because those are `H`'s parents.  If they have those commits, this part of the `git push` is done: your Git sends commit `H` (only).  If they are missing one or more commits, your Git offers the [remaining] parents of `G` and/or `D`, i.e., `F` and `C`.  If they have those commits, this part of the `git push` is done: your Git sends commit `H`, plus commit `G` and/or `D` as needed.

So let's look at what they have:

> ```
>   E--F   <-- featureOne
>  /
> A--B--C--D   <-- branchOne
> ```

Here, they do have commits `F` and `D` already.  So your Git offers `H` and they accept; your Git offers `G` and they accept; your Git offers `D` and they say *no thanks, I already have that one;* and your Git offers commit `F`, and they say *no thanks, I already have that one*.  Your Git then sends them commits `G` and `H` , which they plug into their graph.  Their existing branch names, at this point, still point to commits `F` (`featureOne`) and `D` (`branchOne`) respectively.

At this point, your Git enters the last phase of `git push`, which is to ask them to set some set of their name(s) to some commit(s).  This is where the precise spelling of what you gave to your `git push` command comes in:

> ```
> git push branchOne
> ```

This isn't the right spelling, which would have to be:

```
git push origin branchOne
```

The `origin` part is how you tell your Git what other Git to call up.  The name part, `branchOne`, is short for this alternate spelling:

```
git push origin branchOne:branchOne
```

The left side of the colon `:` character is how your Git finds a starting *commit* to offer.  In this case, your name `branchOne` points to your commit `H`, so that's the commit your Git starts out offering.

The right side of the colon `:` character provides the *branch name* you ask *them* to *set* in their Git repository.  By using `branchOne` here, you will end up asking them to set their name `branchOne` to point to commit `H`.

> Will it merge?

The `git push` command never causes any *merging*.  It just *sends existing commits that you have, that they don't*, then *asks them to set some names* (usually branch names).  It is up to their Git to accept or reject this request to set branch names.

If you're pushing to GitHub, and someone has enabled "protected branch" mode on the branch name `branchOne` in the Git repository on GitHub, they will reject this attempt to change the name, because the branch is protected.

In most cases, however, they will accept this request to change the name.  They currently have their name `branchOne` identifying commit `D`.  Commit `H` has commit `D` as an ancestor—in fact, as an immediate parent—so this operation is a *fast-forward* (not a *fast-forward merge*, just a *fast-forward*), which makes the request acceptable.

Note that this *does not* ask them to set their name `featureOne` at all.  Their name `featureOne` will continue to point wherever it pointed before, such as to commit `F`.  For StackOverflow posting purposes, I would draw that as:

```
    E------F   <-- featureOne
   /        \
  /          G-.
 /          /   \
A--B--C----D-----H   <-- branchOne
```

for instance.  (I've moved `G` forward as it is clearly meant to be a merge of `D` and `F`, and the way you've drawn it, it looks like `D` is a merge of `C` and `G`.)

#### Notes

If you use the colon syntax:

```
git push origin <commit-specifier>:<name>
```

you can use any arbitrary commit specifier on the left side here.  That can be a branch name, a tag name, the name `HEAD`, a relative name like `master~3`, a reflog entry like `develop@{yesterday}`, or even a raw hash ID.  If you use a raw hash ID on the left and you'd like the other Git to create a new *branch name*, you must spell out the full name:

```
git push origin a123456:refs/heads/new-branch
```

An abbreviation like:

```
git push origin a123456:existing-branch
```

relies on *their* Git matching up the name `existing-branch` to one of their existing branch names.

If you use the colon-free form, you *must* use a name, since that name needs to be sent to the other Git.

You can `git push` more than one thing at a time:

```
git push origin master dev feature
```

or:

```
git push origin master~3:refs/heads/new-temp-branch dev a123456:refs/tags/v1.2
```

Assuming the name `new-temp-branch` does not yet exist in the Git at `origin`, this last version uses one relative name (`master~3`) to create a new branch named `new-temp-branch`.  It uses one colon-free expression to send the tip commit of the local `dev` branch and request that they create or update their branch name `dev` correspondingly.  And, it uses a raw hash ID (`a123456`) to request that they create or update their tag-name `v1.2`.  Tag name updates are normally forbidden,<sup>1</sup> so we're expecting this to create a new tag name.

---

<sup>1</sup>There was a bug in Git versions up until 1.8.2 or 1.8.4 that accidentally allowed unforced tag name updates using the same rule as for branch name updates.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation and correcting my diagram. I do have some doubts:  1. "Note that this does not ask them to set their name `featureOne` at all. Their name `featureOne` will continue to point wherever it pointed before, such as to commit `F`". This is on the remote side right? If do me merge of branchOne into featureOne at T2 in local, `featureOne` will have to point to the new commit G right?  2. Say at T2 I do a push of featureOne to remote (`git push origin featureOne`) assuming point 1 in my comment, in remote the `featureOne` will point to `G`?

Comment: 3. Considering my original case, if I want in remote, `featureOne` to point to commit `G`, how would I do that? `git checkout SHA1 of G`?
4. Where did you learn the theroy behind all this? I know the commands but not the theroy of what is actually happening. I have read some answers on SO explaining theroy behind certain git commands, but where this therotical knowledge originally come from? from reading the git source code?

Comment: 1. Their names are in their Gits, which are your remotes, yes. If you take local actions (which is all you *can* do) in *your* Git repository, that affects your names. If you use `git merge` to make new commits, that makes new commits in your Git repository.

Comment: 2. If you run `git push origin featureOne`, your Git will call up their Git, offer the commit at the tip of your `featureOne`, send any other commits required, and then request that they set their name `featureOne` to point to the same commit as your `featureOne` does in your repository. (Note that the *commits* are shared via identical copying; it's the *branch names* that are independent in each Git repository.)

Comment: 3. If you want to have the other Git make changes to its names, you can either log in to the machine that *has* the other Git, and then—locally—make changes to the local names on that machine. Or, you can use `git push` to send requests of the form: *set your name <name> to hash ID <id>*.

Comment: 4. Years of working with Git (including reading some of its source code), plus an attempt (between jobs) to write a book on version control. :-)